# Burninate [refs]? and/or merge with [reference]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There's no reference of when to use the [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs).

The description of the tag says

> The [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs) tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/55168)?

So, the tag itself is ambiguous and has no clear guidelines of when the tag should be used. Most of the times, the tag is used to use the word **reference**.

At the moment, there are 33 questions.

The [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs) is used in conjuction with

1. [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs): [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+reactjs)
2. [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git): [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+git)
3. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) : [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+javascript)
4. [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure): [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+clojure)
5. [controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controller): [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+controller)
6. [ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocaml): [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs+ocaml)

[Does this tag even need to be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/303632)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? - **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? - **No**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? - **No**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? - **No**

The above **4 No** = **Yes to burninate**.

**Can we burninate [refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refs)? and/or merge with[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference)?**

Comment: Looks like it needs to be *burninated*

Comment: I see synonym material IMHO.